# Using a custom authorization manager in WildFly

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I already succeeded in using a custom login module. Now I try to tell WildFly to use my own custom authorization manager using the following code:

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>CustomSecurityDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml:

```
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                ...
                <security-domain name="CustomSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="my.CustomLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="user.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="my.CustomAuthorizationManager" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        ...
```

CustomAuthorizationManager.java:

```
package my;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import io.undertow.security.idm.Account;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.AuthorizationManager;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.Deployment;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.SingleConstraintMatch;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.TransportGuaranteeType;

public class CustomAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager {

    @Override
    public boolean canAccessResource(List<SingleConstraintMatch> arg0, Account arg1, ServletInfo arg2, HttpServletRequest arg3, Deployment arg4) {
        // do something
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String arg0, Account arg1, ServletInfo arg2, HttpServletRequest arg3, Deployment arg4) {
        // do something
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TransportGuaranteeType transportGuarantee(TransportGuaranteeType arg0, TransportGuaranteeType arg1, HttpServletRequest arg2) {
        // do something
        return null;
    }

}
```

By using the debugger and setting breakpoints to my own `CustomAuthorizationManager` and the default `io.undertow.servlet.core.DefaultAuthorizationManager` implementation I could see, that it uses the default instead of my custom implementation. It seems like WildFly ignores the configuration in standalone.xml.
Setting the WildFly debug level to TRACE showed that my CustomAuthorizationManager is deployed correctly. I tried using WildFly 9 and 10, both behave the same way.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I missed a configuration step?

Answer (score 0):

Try `security-management` element as described here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Security+subsystem+configuration

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: you should implement org.jboss.security.authorization.AuthorizationModule class but same for me, configurations seems to be ignored.